# One to Many Relationship in Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, relationship

I'm having trouble with a one-to-many relationship in Laravel 5.5.

I have two tables, one for blog posts and one for authors. The posts table has an author_id column and it's populated with valid author IDs for each blog post. author_id is defined as a foreign key in the posts table migration.

When I load a view that uses the query the author is null because the author_id isn't being included in the generated query.

Post model:

```
public function author(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Author::class);
}
```

I also tried explicitly listing the keys with the same result:

```
return $this->belongsTo(Author::class, 'author_id', 'id');
```

Post repository:

```
public function getPostBySlug(string $slug)
{
    return $this->model
        ->select(
            'posts.title',
            'posts.contents',
            'posts.published_at'
        )
        ->with(['author:first_name,last_name,slug'])
        ->where('posts.slug', '=', $slug)
        ->whereNotNull('posts.published_at')
        ->first();
}
```

Generated query:

```
select `first_name`, `last_name`, `slug` 
from `authors` where `authors`.`id` in ('') 
and `authors`.`deleted_at` is null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't select the `posts.author_id` so without the `author_id` the relationship couldn't be made, either select `*` or exclude the `select` statement or include `posts.author_id` in your select statement, for example:

```
$this->model
    ->select(
        'posts.author_id',
        'posts.title',
        'posts.contents',
        'posts.published_at'
    )
    // rest of the code ...
```

The `foreign key (posts.author_id)` has to be available to build the relationship with `authors`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$users = DB::table('posts')
        ->leftJoin('authors', 'authors.id', '=', 'posts.user_id')
        ->select('posts.author_id','posts.title','posts.contents','posts.published_at',
               'authors.first_name','authors.last_name','authors.slug')
        ->where('posts.slug', '=', $slug)
        ->whereNotNull('posts.published_at')
        ->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

tray the ralation in the following way
:

```
return $this->belongsTo('namespace\author');
```

or reverse way

```
return $this->hasMany('namespace\author');
```